# Aren't layer normalizations on ViTs acting just like batch normalization?

Tags: transformers

I was checking some ViTs implentation like [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_vit.py#L343).

And, as Layernorm (LN) are assigned by channels like `ln1 = nn.LayerNorm(768)`, and the data input of this layer has shape `(N, HW, C)`. Isn't LN acting just like Batchnorm (BN) when normalizing the values over the dims `(N, HW)`?